# Did the Nurse Joys in Kanto neglect their Chansey?

Tags: pokemon

In season 1 of Pokemon, virtually all of the nurse Joys had their own Chansey.  When generation 2 came around, one of the new Pokemon introduced was Blissey, the evolved form of Chansey.  Chansey is a happiness evolver, which leads to my question.  If Chansey evolve through happiness, how did none of the Chansey in Kanto everevolve prior to the introduction of generation 2?  Were all the Chansey in Kanto just neglected or abused?

Comment: It's possible that the Chansey disliked or were scared evolving into Blissey - same problem Ash's Bulbasaur had. Just a speculation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt this is the in or out of universe explanation, but, since there is no other explanation, we only have conjecture to base this on.

However, before you accept your theory as the truth, consider that Pokémon have a choice when evolving.

In episode 14, when Ash's Pikachu loses to Lt. Surge's Raichu, Ash attempts to evolve Pikachu by means of a thunderstone, to which Pikachu declines. Perhaps the Chancy wish to remain chancy for whatever reason, but like I said, we can only assume as there is no answer.

Comment: You raise a very good point here about pokemon choosing whether or not they evolve.  But this still raises a question.  Why were none of the Kanto Chansey willing to evolve?

Comment: Perhaps Blissy is deligated to another section of health care or perhaps Blissy's larger body, with its added protrusions, simply doesn't suit a health care enviroment. I mean, Chancy is, for the most part, a consistent mass, but Blissy has those strange, almost feather like things sticking out of it. Thus, I surmise that they might get in the way, and so, Blissy would make a far less efficient assistant that Chancy.

Comment: In that case, why would they evolve at all? Seems like a malpractice suit waiting to happen.

Comment: Well, Blissy and Chancy aren't just used for healthcare, they're Pokémon after all.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things to note:

1. The Johto region, and by extension Blissey, didn't exist at the time those episodes were made. As far as everyone was concerned, Chansey was a fully evolved Pokemon.
2. Chansey don't evolve simply by being happy. As with all happiness evolutions, the Pokemon must *level up* whilst having a high happiness rating. In the anime, Pokemon can evolve outside of battle, but this tends to be to protect their trainers from harm. Even if we assume that the Nurse Joys have caught their Chansey with Pokeballs and are effectively their trainers, I don't suppose many Nurse Joys have been in that amount of danger, nor do they seem the battling type. Therefore, it's not much of a surprise that there are mainly still Chansey in Pokemon centres and not Blissey.

So, to answer your question, no, Nurse Joys aren't neglectful. Their Chansey just don't have a reason to have evolved yet.

Besides, have you ever seen a Nurse Joy? I don't think they're capable of being anything other than caring about each and every Pokemon they encounter.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say here, but consider this.  In-universe, Johto did not magically appear out of nowhere along with 100 never before seen pokemon.  The Johto region, along with the second generation of pokemon, had existed as long as any other region.  And many nurse Joys outside of Kanto have Blisseys.  So what were the nurse Joys in Kanto doing differently?  I am almost certain that the writers merely failed to consider the implications of introducing new evolutions of pre-existing pokemon, but I still want to see if it is possible to fix this plot-hole in universe.

Comment: It sounds like the only way it'll get fixed is with a retcon. At the time of these episodes' creation, as stated in the answer, Blissey simply *didn't exist*, outside of Johto or otherwise.

Comment: There's no reason for them to retcon. Kanto, Johto, Hoenn and Sinnoh _all_ primarily have Chansey in their Pokemon Centres. Audino are used in Unova, Wigglytuff in Kalos, and Blissey+Comfey in Alola.

Comment: If you can find an official source stating that Nurse Joys are anything except kind and caring, I'll be amazed. And Brock will probably destroy it.

Comment: Your first point is excellent. +1 (Sportsmanship badge)

Comment: Trying to square later evolutions against previous regions becomes very problematic, and at some point you need to just shrug and move on. Take Pokemon like Pichu, which don't exist in Kanto, but are just the baby versions of Pikachu. There is no reason in-universe why Pikachus wouldn't be born as Pichus in all regions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to start off by saying this is one of the many differences the anime has from the canon games. In the games, there's a fixed condition as to when a Pokémon evolves,  whether it be at a certain level, trading,  certain item etc. However, in the anime, this is different.

**Pokemon get to "choose" when they want to evolve in the anime**. I suppose it's for comic relief. I mean, a Bulbasaur doesn't look as cute as a Venusaur now does it? An excellent example would be Ash's little green friend.

> Its biggest fear appears to be of its fully evolved form, Venusaur, demonstrated in Island of the Giant Pokémon and The Ghost of Maiden's Peak, both times where it was paralyzed in fear by fake Venusaur. Interestingly enough, it defied the wishes of the first real Venusaur it encountered, demonstrating that Bulbasaur is a courageous Pokémon when standing up for something it believes in.
>
> [Bulbasaur Bulbapedia entry](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ash%27s_Bulbasaur#Personality_and_characteristics)

This applies to many other Pokémon we meet throughout the anime and it's the same for the Chanseys. **They just don't want to evolve**, it's not because they were neglected. I highly doubt Nurse Joys, the people in charge of caring for Pokémon, would let their own Pokémon be neglected.

> Chansey is similar to her Trainer, Nurse Joy, as both are caring and nice to Trainers and Pokémon.
>
> [Chansey Bulbapedia entry](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nurse_Joy%27s_Chansey#Personality_and_characteristics)